# How to prevent READ_PHONE_STATE Android permission

Tags: android, codenameone, android-permissions

I am trying to create a new release of my Codename One app for Android. When I upload the APK to the Google Play Console, I get an error that my APK uses `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` and that I do need a privacy policy to be able to use that permission.

In the Codename One blog I read:

`android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` - is triggered by com.codename1.ads package, com.codename1.components.Ads, com.codename1.components.ShareButton, com.codename1.media, com.codename1.push, Display.getUdid() & Display.getMsisdn(). This permission is required for media in order to suspend audio playback when you get a phone call.

But my app does not use ads, does not use sharing, does not use media, does not use push and does not use UDID nor MSISDN. Hence, I have no clue why I would need this permission (which indeed is present in the generated APK).

How can I prevent this permission being added to the APK (or how can I detect why this permission is added).

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

```
#
#Sat Sep 28 17:12:49 BST 2019
codename1.vendor=Frans van Gool
codename1.displayName=S\u00F3 Verbos
codename1.icon=/C\:/EclipseData/JustVerbs/GaloDeBarcelos.png
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.secondaryTitle=S\u00F3 Verbos
codename1.version=1.20
codename1.mainName=Main
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
libVersion=212
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.android.keystorePassword=**************
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nativej2me.res
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.android.keystore=/C\:/eclipseData/JustVerbs/keychain.ks
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=justverbs
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.packageName=nl.griffelservices.justverbs
```

Comment: It isn't even used for most of these features either. Please list all the android.* build hints for your app and all the cn1libs you are using

Comment: The only build hint I use are `java.version=8` and `ios.newStorageLocation=true`, so no android build hints. Furthermore I do not use any cn1libs. The app is very simple; except for the classes in the `ui`package and its sub-packages, my code only uses the `components.MultiButton`, `io.Storage`, `io.Util` and `io.Log` classes from CN1.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error you got from google? That doesn't make sense based on what you're describing as it would imply no apps can be submitted to google play and we submit apps all the time. We don't use that permission anymore.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error to the question. Note that the error is correct: I opened the APK and the manifest indeed states that permission. For completeness sake, i also add the CN1 versions I use: `#
#Sat Sep 28 17:14:38 BST 2019
CodenameOne_SRCzip=90
CodenameOneJar=90
CodeNameOneBuildClientJar=17
CLDC11Jar=18
JavaSEJar=90`

Comment: can you share a picture of your manifest permission part ?

Comment: Can you place the full codenameone_settings.properties file here? There might be a legacy setting I haven't thought about

Comment: I added a screenshot of the manifest permission part and the full codenameone_settings.properties file to the question. Note that I also wonder why I would need the `WAKE_LOCK` and the c2dm `RECEIVE` permissions. The `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are probably needed by the `io.Storage` and `io.Log` classes, and the `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` are probably standard for CN1 (although my app does not use the network).

Comment: Are you aware that your keystore password is public? `codename1.android.keystorePassword=W8dmIhJcS1TC`?

Comment: Are you using `sendSMS`?
This might be triggering the permission for you. We'll disable that as that permission is no longer necessary for `sendSMS` in interactive mode.

Comment: No I am not using `sendSMS`. I am only using UI classes and file IO (`Storage` and `Log`).

Comment: @FransvanGool You are not alone. I have the same issue and my app only uses Bluetooth to communicate with health devices. I never request this READ_PHONE_STATE permission, yet playstore says it is.

Comment: @BrianReinhold Since I couldn't figure out the cause of this issue, I finally decided to rewrite my app to native Android. I only deployed to Android anyway, so that wasn't a big deal to me. It wasn't even too much work, since I have a good separation between the UI an logic part of my app. I like the codename one approach (multi platform, nice UI framework) but in the end native Android was better for me.

Comment: @FransvanGool I found later that it is a bug in the PlayStore console. There is a work a round that I have implemented but not tried. In the manifest you can negate a permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:node="remove" /> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/removing-default-permissions

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this works (this text has always been here - not sure why it was hidden)

```
<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

see:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/removing-default-permissions

(apparently this link no longer works)
I have implemented it but have not tried it (many moons later - I have tried it and it does work). I did not know one could remove permissions in the manifest - first of all I never expected they would get added!

Comment: After I deployed the native Android version of my app, I deleted the codename one version, so I cannot test your solution. However, in the native version of my app, I didn't need to remove the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, so apparently it wasn't added by default. Since it was added in the codename one version, it seems an issue with the codename one build process to me. However, it is still very well possible that removing the permission this way will work around the issue.

Comment: Note that your link refers to a the react native framework, not the codename one framework. But it is still possible that removing the permission this way will work around the issue, in react native, codename one or both.

Comment: I have seen the same process used somewhere else; I think it was stack overflow. But this also appears to be something new when I added support for Android 10 and uploaded to the store. I did not have this issue previously; or at least I never got a warning. I will find out if this works when I upload the next version

Comment: The link is now dead. Please copy the relevant parts to your answer next time. Thanks!

Comment: @ocroquette The full text (implementation) is present. When I went to edit the answer, the text was there. Not sure why it was not visible when out of edit mode. So I placed the actual code into a code block and copied the link to an area after the code (and noted it no longer works). I keep it there to note that I did not figure this out.